# How do you create the small container containing smaller pictures of the whole image?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-test

[image]

How can I click on those small images and get a larger preview of the same image that I had clicked?

Answer (score 2):

By manipulating the height of the container you can achieve the smaller images and You can wrap container with InkWell Widget then on OnTap navigate to the preview dialog or separate screen.

I hole this helps you!